# Is JRequest::getVar('Variable') is safe or not in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla1.6

i want to know whether JRequest::getVar() function is good enough to prevent sql injection or XSS or it must be better to use some other things to prevent XSS or sql injection in joomla sites.

Comment: Why would you think a method that has nothing to do with databases, would magically protect you from SQL injection?

Comment: Jrequest::getVar() acts just like $_REQUEST, $_POST and $_GET. In the official joomla website, they have wriiten their that it must be good to use Jrequest::getVar() instead of using post and get as it is filtering the bad characters.

Comment: Eh.  Filtering (particularly at the request level) is usually the wrong way to go about it.  Consider that if Joomla were filtering out `'`s, you'd no longer be able to have a text field containing "Eat at Joe's", and anyone with the last name of "O'Malley" would be told their name's invalid.  :P  Escape data as you need it, for the domain it's going to.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are developing for Joomla 2.5+, you are not supposed to use `JRequest` anymore as it's deprecated.

New way of getting request variables is like this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
// expecting integer, default 0
$user_id = $jinput->post->get('user_id', 0, 'INT');
// expecting string, default empty string
$user_name = $jinput->post->get('user_name', '', 'STRING')
```

Third parameter for `$jinput` is filter, so if you know you want e.g. integer to be returned, set appropriate filter.

Note that for using `JInput`, `magic quotes` must be turned off.

To protect from sql injection, use

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
// $value is not safe
$value = $db->quote($value);
```

And against XSS

```
$filter = JFilterInput::getInstance();
// $value is not safe
$value = $filter->clean($value);
```

After reading your comments, I just want to add that there are no "bad characters" per se. Also, filtering against sql injection or xss is very different. For better understanding about filtering and escaping, reffer to [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Note however the entire Joomla Core in 2.5 uses JRequest because JInput fails on any site with magic quotes still turned on! (deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed in 5.4 I know - but still too many sites have this feature turned on still!)

Comment: Just to add to the great answer above, types that can be filtered include-int, integer, uint, float, double,bool,boolean, word, alnum, cmd,base64, string, html, safe_html,array,path,raw, and username. More info about filter types at http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput On a different note, please consider supporting a Joomla StackExchange network at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla